# VBA Expected end of statement can't find the syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply a formula to a column in and I get an "expected end of statement error"

```
  Sub Test()
    
    
    Range("T2:T").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF($D2= "EMMEGI SCA 550 SMALL SAW","OK","Not OK")"
    
    End Sub
```

when the error pops up `EMMEGI` is highlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Double Quotes when creating formulas with VBA:

```
Range("T2:T").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF($D2=""EMMEGI SCA 550 SMALL SAW"",""OK"",""Not OK"")"
```